# Is it 'vectorizing' or 'vectoring' an image?

Tags: vector, terminology

What do you call the action when you transform an image from raster into a vector? Is it "vectorizing" or "vectoring"?

Comment: Vectoring is moving to a specific heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"vector" in the context of digital file formats isn't a verb. As such, neither 'vectoring' or 'vectorizing' is technically correct. Preferably, you'd say some form of:

- creating a vector illustration
- converting a raster image to a vector image
- illustrate using vector illustration software

But, as we all know, humans turn all sorts of nouns and ajectives into verbs and, as such, we should *google* it (see what I did there!?)

- "vectoring an image" = 315,000 results
- "vectorizing an image" = 103,000 results

Is that grammatical proof of anything? No. Not really.

Comment: This is a surprisingly good answer to a question like this

Comment: The second sentence in this answer doesn’t really make sense (and it’s also not true in my experience): _vectorise_ is a verb derived from the noun _vector_, so the fact that _vector_ in the context of digital file formats isn’t a verb doesn’t in any way entail that _vectorise_ would not be a perfectly cromulent verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, that's pretty much what I'm saying. "Google" isn't technically a verb but we've made it a verb. Language is funny like that. I also have to up-vote any use of the term cromulent!

Comment: This is how I've always seen the usage... as incorrect.. but then... I think of "rasterizing" - which *technically* is incorrect for the same reasons. So that kind of blows the "it's not technically correct" mentality out of the water. :) I don't like using or hearing "vectoring/vectorizing" but I no longer shiver due to improper grammar or possibly fictitious word usage.

Comment: @DA01 Well, _google_ **is** a verb, exactly because it’s been verbed. But _vectorise_ is slightly different even so: verbing through zero-derivation from proper nouns is often somewhat frowned upon by some (it’s somehow ‘impure’), but the completely productive pattern of deriving causatives or factitives from nouns by adding _-ise_ is quite unremarkable. Saying that something isn’t “technically” a word doesn’t really make any sense. Any word that is used and understood reliably is a word; nothing technical about it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, I know. We're debating language. Language is imperfect. I agree with everything you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing) is what i've seen everywhere.

> In computer graphics, image tracing, raster-to-vector conversion or vectorization is the conversion of raster graphics into vector graphics.

Answer (score 2):

- Raster ~ Vector
- Rasterize ~ Vectorize
- Rasterizing ~ Vectorizing

To me the terms "Vectorize/Vectorizing" don't *sound* right in my ears.  But that alone doesn't make them incorrect. The English language is a constantly evolving thing. Given "vector"'s direct counterpart, these would be the correct usage. You wouldn't ever be "rastering". So, conversely you would never be "vectoring" either in the context of digital images.

Note that "Vector" has more definitions than "raster". You *can* be "vectoring". It's a *physical movement*, however, not a digital image adjustment. i.e. "vectoring to coordinates".